# How to save previous data from previous view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ive set up the first question to my game, its a word game, but every time I press the close button when the question is answered and go back to the questions page, I need the user to not have the option to play that question again, in fact the screen should remain the way they exited it, with all the data saved....

In other words they must leave the question the way it was when they were playing it!

How is this done...

Any tutorials or even advise to solve my problem would be great...

The button to the first question is on modal and it modals back to the menu where the other questions are!

Comment: Why don`t you use NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Is it static game or dynamic game

Comment: @Vineesh TP what does static or dynamic game mean?

Comment: I mean game score is save to to server or your device itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your game data (which questions have been answered etc.) should  not be saved in any view or view controller, but in a `GameState` object. Create a `GameState` object, keep a reference to it (either implement it as a singleton, or store it as a property in your `AppDelegate`), and set all answered questions in it. Then you can always ask the GameState object which questions have already been answered, from anywhere in your app.

Comment: So I would create a game state object! But what happens if I want to save the whole view? would I save that in the delegate as well?

Comment: Actually I believe it would be best to save the whole game the way it is, thus the user cannot have a second change ever! how is that done? same way?

Comment: Then you have to persist the GameState, for example by setting its attributes in the NSUserDefaults, or better store it in a database (look into Managed Objects).